# WatchKit: direct communication with the containing iOS app

Tags: ios, web-services, background, watchkit

I just get started with `WatchKit` and I'm trying to do this (if I'm not wrong, it is possible to do): I'd like the `WatchKit` Extension to ask the containing app for requesting some data to a web service, and then return the service response to the Extension to update the `WatchKit` App interface accordingly.

As I read in [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW1), yo can call the `openParentApplication:reply:` method in the `WatchKit` Extension to request something to its containing app, and then the `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` method in the `AppDelegate` of the containing app should be called. Once this method called, I need to perform the service request, wait for its response, and then send it back to the Extension.

However, when I run the `WatchKit` App scheme in the simulator, the `openParentApplication:reply:` method is called, but a breakpoint within the `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` is not reached. So I'm not even able to test if I can correctly perform the web service request and get its response back.

What could I be missing? Should I configure somehow the schema to reach breakpoints in the containing app as well? Is it needed to declare some kind of background feature for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29052000/1342462) which will allow you to open the iOS app from the Watch Extension and getting a reply back.

In order to debug the iOS app while running the Watch Extension, you should follow the steps explained [here](https://mkswap.net/m/blog/How+to+debug+an+iOS+app+while+the+WatchKit+app+is+currently+running+in+the+simulator).

Comment: Thanks! One more question: since getting the response from the service is an asynchronous task... what should be the correct way to wait for the response, and then return it to the WatchKit Extension?

Comment: Simple...call the `reply` closure once the asynchronous task is complete. This will most likely be in the completion handler closure of the asynchronous task.

Comment: Understood, thanks! I'm also calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` just in case the asynchronous request takes too long... I think this is the correct way.